# Moving point along lines

Tags: java

I draw a shape, which looks like letter "Y". Then I draw a small point at the bottom of it.

Let's say the shape is 3 lines, like so:

[image: the problem]

I want to move this point along line 1, then line 2, then back along line 2, then line 3, and finally back to the start at the bottom of line 1.

It moves with speed specified by slider.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class yyyyy extends JFrame{

private Komponent komponent;
private Timer timer;
private int tick = 0;
private int speed = 4;
private int x1 = 225, y1 = 300, y2 = 225, x3 = 150, y3 = 150, x4 = 300; 
private int x = x1, y = y1;

class Komponent extends JComponent{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4028514932033769012L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {



        if(tick< y1-y2){
            x = x1;
            y = y1-tick;
        }
        else if(tick>y1-y2 && tick < 2*(y1-y2)){
            x = x1-tick + (y1-y2);
            y = y2-tick + (y1-y2);
        }
        else if(tick>2*(y1-y2) && tick < 3*(y1-y2)){
            x = x3 + tick - 2*(y1-y2);
            y = y3 + tick - 2*(y1-y2);
        }
        else if(tick>3*(y1-y2)&& tick < 4*(y1-y2)){
            x = x1 + tick - 3*(y1-y2);
            y = y2 - tick + 3*(y1-y2);
        }
        else if(tick>4*(y1-y2)&& tick < 5*(y1-y2)){
            x = x4 - tick + 4*(y1-y2);
            y = y3 + tick - 4*(y1-y2);
        }
        else{
            x = x1;
            y = y2 + tick - 5*(y1-y2);
        }
        arg0.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        arg0.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2);
        arg0.drawLine(x1,y2,x3,y3);
        arg0.drawLine(x1, y2, x4, y3);

        arg0.setColor(Color.RED);
        arg0.fillOval(x-5, y-5, 10, 10);
        super.paintComponent(arg0);
    }

}
public yyyyy (String string){
    super(string);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100,100,550,550);
    add(komponent=new Komponent());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("Animacja");
    cb.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            if(cb.isSelected()){
                timer.start();
            }
            else{
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
    panel.add(cb);
    timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tick+=speed;
            if(tick > 6*(y1 -y2)){
                tick -= 6*(y1-y2);
            }
            if(tick < 0){
                tick = 6*(y2-y1);
            }
            komponent.repaint();
        }
    });

    final JSlider speedSlider = new JSlider(-30,30,speed);
    panel.add(speedSlider);
    speedSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            speed = speedSlider.getValue();
            komponent.repaint();
        }
    });
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new yyyyy("wat");

        }
    });
}

}
```

Now I have 2 problems:
 1. Is the resetting of tick defined properly? I feel like it should go to 0 after being 2 * the sum of distances of all lines. 
 2. The part of the code I marked with comment. How can I check what the current x and y of the point should be? I tried doing that from line equation, but not much success (point was always just shooting outside of the window).

EDIT: Code updated.

Comment: 1. No it is not defined properly. You need to have the current location of the tick (x,y) be global variables. Then as you are timestepping, you can change the global variables at the necessary speed/direction. As is, your ticks (x,y) location will never change.

Comment: 2. What you said is correct, you need to do the math from the line equation. Just make sure that the (x,y) locations are global variables and at a specific time you are changing the (x,y) locations along the correct line at the correct speed.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I'm not sure I understand your 1st answer. My tick is not x,y it's just a number which is the distance in pixels I move along line. Why is my tick resetting no good?

Comment: You are drawing your tick as an oval using `arg0.fillOval()`. This method is being run with the center of your tick at location (x,y) in your `paintComponent()` method. I haven't even looked at how you are using your timer and the variable `tick` because as-is, the (x,y) values of your tick are never changed.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I've posted the updated code. It now works fine when going with positive speed, but when I go with negative speed it falls out of picture again. Can you take a look and see if I didn't mess up anything now?

Comment: If what you mean is that it is fine when variable `speed>0`, have you considered that your logic is off when `speed < 0`? For starters, I see that in your timer's `actionPerformed()` method, you need to change it to `if(tick < 0) tick += 6*(y1-y2);` for your logic to be perfectly symmetric.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Thank you, haven't noticed I'm missing the + there. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question was already answered in the comment (and although it was mainly a debugging hint, and although this is not really an answer...) I'd like to recommend you to generalize this.

You should probably to model each and every segment manually, with a fixed set of coordinates. Instead, you could create a general "path", that should be followed. The position on the path can be defined as a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

Then, the timing and interpolation are separated, and the timing itself can be handled separately. You can then even add nifty animation effects, for example, add some `Math.sin` somewhere and obtain interesting ease-in/ease-out effects.

However, here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing an example of how such a generic path follower could be implemented. It may changed from following an `Y` to following an `X` just by changing the creation of the `PathFollower` instance in the `main` method.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class PathFollowerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final PathFollower pathFollower = createPathFollowerY();
        //final PathFollower pathFollower = createPathFollowerX();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI(pathFollower);
            }
        });
    }

    private static PathFollower createPathFollowerY()
    {
        Point2D p0 = new Point2D.Double(225, 300);
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D.Double(225, 225);
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D.Double(150, 150);
        Point2D p3 = new Point2D.Double(300, 150);
        PathFollower pathFollower = new PathFollower();
        pathFollower.addPoint(p0);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p1);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p2);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p1);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p3);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p1);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p0);
        return pathFollower;
    }

    private static PathFollower createPathFollowerX()
    {
        Point2D p0 = new Point2D.Double(150, 300);
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D.Double(225, 225);
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D.Double(150, 150);
        Point2D p3 = new Point2D.Double(300, 300);
        Point2D p4 = new Point2D.Double(300, 150);
        PathFollower pathFollower = new PathFollower();
        pathFollower.addPoint(p0);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p1);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p2);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p1);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p4);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p1);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p3);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p1);
        pathFollower.addPoint(p0);
        return pathFollower;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(final PathFollower pathFollower)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setBounds(100, 100, 550, 550);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        PathFollowerPanel pathFollowerPanel = 
            new PathFollowerPanel(pathFollower);
        f.getContentPane().add(pathFollowerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final PathFollowerController pathFollowerController = 
            new PathFollowerController(
                pathFollower, pathFollowerPanel);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("Animacja");
        cb.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                pathFollowerController.setRunning(cb.isSelected());
            }
        });
        panel.add(cb);

        final JSlider speedSlider = new JSlider(-30, 30, 0);
        panel.add(speedSlider);
        speedSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                pathFollowerController.setSpeed(speedSlider.getValue());
            }
        });
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class PathFollowerController
{
    private int speed = 0;
    private PathFollower pathFollower;
    private PathFollowerPanel pathFollowerPanel;

    private final Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener()
    {
        private double alpha = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            alpha += speed / 500.0;
            alpha %= 1.0;
            while (alpha < -1.0)
            {
                alpha += 1.0;
            }
            pathFollower.setAlpha(alpha < 0 ? -alpha : alpha);
            pathFollowerPanel.repaint();
        }
    });

    PathFollowerController(PathFollower pathFollower,
        PathFollowerPanel pathFollowerPanel)
    {
        this.pathFollower = pathFollower;
        this.pathFollowerPanel = pathFollowerPanel;
    }

    void setRunning(boolean running)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            timer.start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}

class PathFollower
{
    private final List<Point2D> points;
    private Shape path;
    private double pathLength = -1;
    private double alpha = 0;

    PathFollower()
    {
        points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
    }

    void addPoint(Point2D p)
    {
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY()));
        path = null;
        pathLength = -1;
    }

    void setAlpha(double alpha)
    {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    Point2D getCurrentPoint()
    {
        return computePoint(alpha);
    }

    Shape getPath()
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            path = createPath();
        }
        return path;
    }

    private Shape createPath()
    {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        {
            Point2D p = points.get(i);
            double x = p.getX();
            double y = p.getY();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                path.moveTo(x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                path.lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    private double computePathLength()
    {
        double pathLength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            Point2D p0 = points.get(i);
            Point2D p1 = points.get(i + 1);
            pathLength += p0.distance(p1);
        }
        return pathLength;
    }

    private Point2D computePoint(double alpha)
    {
        if (pathLength < 0)
        {
            pathLength = computePathLength();
        }
        double alphaPosition = alpha * pathLength;
        double accumulatedLength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            Point2D p0 = points.get(i);
            Point2D p1 = points.get(i + 1);
            double distance = p0.distance(p1);
            double nextLength = accumulatedLength + distance;
            if (nextLength >= alphaPosition)
            {
                double localAlpha = 
                    (alphaPosition - accumulatedLength) / distance;
                double x = p0.getX() + localAlpha * (p1.getX() - p0.getX());
                double y = p0.getY() + localAlpha * (p1.getY() - p0.getY());
                return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
            }
            accumulatedLength = nextLength;
        }
        Point2D p = points.get(points.size() - 1);
        return new Point2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY());
    }

}

class PathFollowerPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final PathFollower pathFollower;

    PathFollowerPanel(PathFollower pathFollower)
    {
        this.pathFollower = pathFollower;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g.draw(pathFollower.getPath());

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        Point2D p = pathFollower.getCurrentPoint();
        double r = 5;
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(
            p.getX() - r, p.getY() - r, r + r, r + r));
    }
}
```